# Cancelling edit of a question title doesn't revert to the prior title when edited using inline edit

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, inline-editor

Inline edits show a real time edit of the title. However, if I hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> or click on cancel, the title edits do not go back to the previous version ( although the edit is not actually saved).

### [image]

[image]

---

Hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> or click on cancel

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[And another bug gone](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rNQRfBAzSzo&feature=player_detailpage#t=49s).