# Title changes in /review inline edit don't update

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, inline-editor

This seems potentially similar or related to [Cancelling edit of a question title doesn't revert to the prior title when edited using inline edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98831/cancelling-edit-of-a-question-title-doesnt-revert-to-the-prior-title-when-edite) (but I'm not positive).

I went into `/review` and [edited the title, body, and tags of a question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8050284/2). When I hit `Save` the tags and body immediately updated on the `/review` page, but the title did not, which made me think that I had forgotten to fix it up. However, if I click through to the question or hit `edit` again, I can see that the title has, in fact, been changed.

Screenshot:

[image]

**Edit:** I should probably add that I'm using Firefox 8 on Windows 7, but it was also reproducible with Firefox 7.0.1 (updated a few minutes ago). I haven't tried any other browsers.

Comment: Took me a while to find a title worth editing, but I can now confirm that this is reproducable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it so the title will update after you submit a title update. It does not update in /review while your are typing ... but that is not a huge issue in my opinion.

Comment: Was this fix only for StackOverflow, or network-wide? I just discovered this same issue on english.stackexchange.