# Curly quotes in titles revert to straight quotes after canceling an edit

Tags: bug, edits, markdown, title

This scenario is happening to me in Chrome 28 and IE9 (the only two browsers I have installed):

1. Be signed in
2. Observe a question whose title contains quotes which have been rendered in the "curly" fashion (e.g. [How to get generic type "T" of class when reused in method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17819803/how-to-get-generic-type-t-of-class-when-reused-in-method))
3. Click "Edit" at the bottom of a question
4. Click "Cancel" next to the "Save Edits" button
5. Observe that the curly quotes in the title have reverted to straight quotes

This is such a minor thing that I'm surprised I even noticed it, but I wanted to report it nonetheless.

---

Related:

- [Are double quotes being replaced in titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38098/are-double-quotes-being-replaced-in-titles)
- [Smart quotes in parentheses point the wrong way ("example") ["tst"] {"tst"}](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34587/smart-quotes-in-parentheses-point-the-wrong-way-example-tst-tst)
- [Cancelling edit of a question title doesn't revert to the prior title when edited using inline edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98831/cancelling-edit-of-a-question-title-doesnt-revert-to-the-prior-title-when-edite)

Comment: Thankfully, refreshing the page sets it back to fancy quotes. Crisis averted! (What I'm trying to say is, yes I can reproduce it. Chrome 28 too)

Comment: There is nothing "minor" about the bastardization of typography. If I had a nickel for every time I've replaced a hyphen with an em- or en-dash, I could come close to countering Michael Dell's buyout offer.